# Seleccionar el minimo de los promedios de varios grupos

Tags: sql, db2

En sql intento hacer lo siguiente:
Tengo un set de datos con 3 columnas. Una es localidad, otra son escuelas y otra es rendimiento.
Lo que quiero es hacer el promedio de rendimiento según la localidad de grupos de escuelas y seleccionar luego el mínimo.
tengo esto:

```
select localidad, avg(rendimiento) como R from tabla
group by localidad
order by R limit 1
```

esto da el resultado pero ¿cómo se haría una sub-query usando `min()` y `avg()`?

Comment: En qué base de datos? Ese `como` te funciona????

Comment: Hola! perdona el retraso. Es en DB2 de ibm cloud usando sql.
El código que marco ya da el resultado correcto pero queria intentar hacerlo con una subquery.

Comment: Dale, procura siempre marcar la pregunta usando la etiqueta del motor, que mira que yo no conozco nada nada de DB2 y no tenía cómo responder si ni siquiera conocía bien la sintaxis :) Gracias por la aclaración. Aquí creo que es válido que indiques de qué tablas (estructura) sacas esos datos para que te puedan ayudar a cambiar la consulta. Y un par de datos de prueba con el resultado esperado ayudarían mucho a que puedan replicar tu ejercicio